# How to erase a bitstream from an FFPGA using a microcontroller?

Tags: fpga, stm32, intel-fpga

How can I erase the bitstream that is stored in flash memory from an FFPGA (Flash FPGA, e.g. MAX10) using a microcontroller or any other logic?

I analyzed [MAX10 documentation](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_handbook.pdf) and still didn't find any easy (and fully documented) solution.

It seems like I could use the [Altera On-Chip Flash IP Core](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_ufm.pdf), but it requires to power up the FPGA, load the bitstream, and then eventually erase the proper CFM memory. Maybe I could use JTAG In-System Programming and somehow invoke ISC_ERASE command? Is there any other way that requires less power?

Comment: Erasing flash requires power. What do you mean by 'power' anyway? An 'IP Core' is something that a system-on-chip designer can license but it's probably equal to what's in Alteras own chips.

Comment: MAX10 has two different flash-memories, which one so you want to erase and why? Is this part of your application, like say you want your device to self-destruct or erase a crypto-key?

Comment: @user1890202: I want to erase configuration memory, not UFM, but I think erasing both memories can be done the same way. Yes, this is part of my application. I would like to erase bitstream before FPGA enters user mode (page 491 in [MAX10 Handbook](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/m10_handbook.pdf)).

Comment: that means that once you loose power your product is dead. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user1890202: no, it should be dead once microcontroller decide it should be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The JTAG commands required to program or erase the FPGA are defined by IEEE Std 1532

https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1532-2002.html

The manufacturere should provide a BSDL file that defines the command set for your specific FPGA.  Having both the BSDL file the IEEE 1532, and the IEEE 1149 standards should together provide all the information required to send the

You first need to send the ISC_ENABLE command to enter programming mode.  Then send ISC_ERASE, to erase the portion of flash memory.then ISC_DISABLE when you are done.

Comment: I figured that out, but this solution seems to work only when `Verify protect` feature is off. Anyway, I hope that there is other solution.